# MySQL NULL or NOT NULL That is The Question?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-null

What is the difference between NULL and NOT NULL? And when should they be used?

Comment: the title brought a smile on me :D

Comment: It is a very classic question. But it would get more spotlights if add EMPTY  i.e. `value =''` to these comparison and to distinguish. I am sure people will come back again if they one day confront with '' (EMPTY).

Comment: This doesn't have anything specific to do with MySQL

Answer (score 59, accepted):

NULL means you do not have to provide a value for the field...

NOT NULL means you must provide a value for the fields.

For example, if you are building a table of registered users for a system, you might want to make sure the user-id is always populated with a value (i.e.   NOT NULL), but the optional spouses name field, can be left empty (NULL)

Comment: Outside of JDBC, MySQL lets you omit value for a `NOT NULL` column *if* there is a `DEFAULT` on the column. I have noticed this seems to not make sense to some programmers, but that is how it works.

Comment: @staticsan It's not true, or at least very misleading, to say that "MySQL lets you omit value for a `NOT NULL` column" - some value must be supplied (that's exactly what `NOT NULL` means), and if you don't supply it then MySQL will supply the `DEFAULT` value. If the column does not define a `DEFAULT` value, MySQL may still supply the implicit default value for the data type when strict mode is not enabled. ([docs link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html))

Comment: @AirThomas You and I have described the exact same mechanism in nearly the same way. The only difference is that outside of strict mode, `NOT NULL` in MySQL actually means the column will never store nor return a null.

Answer (score 18):

I would suggest

- Use NOT NULL on every field if you can
- Use NULL if there is a sensible reason it can be null

Having fields which don't have a meaningful meaning for NULL nullable is likely to introduce bugs, when nulls enter them by accident. Using NOT NULL prevents this.

The commonest reason for NULL fields is that you have a foreign key field which is options, i.e. not always linked, for a "zero or one" relationship.

If you find you have a table with lots of columns many of which can be NULL, that starts sounding like an antipattern, consider whether vertical partitioning makes more sense in your application context :)

There is another useful use for NULL - making all the columns in an index NULL will stop an index record being created for that row, which optimises indexes; you may want to index only a very small subset of rows (e.g. for an "active" flag set on only 1% or something) - making an index which starts with a column which is usually NULL saves space and optimises that index.

Answer (score 11):

> What is the difference between NULL and NOT NULL?

When creating a table or adding a column to a table, you need to specify the column value optionality using either `NULL` or `NOT NULL`. `NOT NULL` means that the column can not have a `NULL` value for any record; `NULL` means `NULL` is an allowable value (even when the column has a foreign key constraint). Because `NULL` isn't a value, you can see why some call it optionality - because database table requires that in order to have a column, there must be an instance of the column for every record within the table.

> And when should they be used?

That is determined by your business rules.
Generally you want as many columns as possible to be `NOT NULL` because you want to be sure data is always there.

Answer (score 5):

`NOT NULL` means that a column cannot have the `NULL` value in it - instead, if nothing is specified when inserting a row for that column, it will use whatever default is specified (or if no default is specified, whatever MySQL's default is for that type).

Fields that aren't `NOT NULL` can potentially have their value as `NULL` (which essentially means a missing/unknown/unspecified value). `NULL` behaves differently than normal values, [see here for more info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html).

Answer (score 4):

As others have answered, `NOT NULL` simply means that `NULL` is not a permitted value. However, you will always have the option of empty string `''` (for `varchar`) or `0` (for `int`), etc.

One nice feature when using `NOT NULL` is that you can get an error or warning should you forget set the column's value during `INSERT`. (assuming the `NOT NULL` column has no `DEFAULT`)

---

The main hiccup with allowing `NULL` columns is that they will never be found with the `<>` (not equal) operator. For example, with the following `category`s

```
Desktops
Mobiles
NULL -- probably embedded devices
```

The `=` operator works as expected

```
select * from myTable where category="Desktops";
```

However, the `<>` operator will exclude any `NULL` entries.

```
select * from myTable where category<>"Mobiles";
-- returns only desktops, embedded devices were not returned
```

This can be the cause of subtle bugs, especially if the column has no `NULL` data during testing initial, but later some `NULL` values are added due to subsequent development. For this reason I set all the columns to `NOT NULL`.

---

However, it can be helpful to allow `NULL` values when using a `UNIQUE` `KEY`/`INDEX`. Normally a unique key requires the column (or combination of columns) to be unique for the whole table. Unique keys are a great safeguard that the database will enforce for you.

In some cases, you may want the safeguard for most of the rows, but there are exceptions.

If any column referenced by that particular `UNIQUE KEY` is `NULL`, then the uniqueness will no longer be enforced for that row. Obviously this would only work if you permit `NULL`s on that column, understanding the hiccup I explained above.

---

If you decide to allow `NULL` values, consider writing your `<>` statements with an additional condition to detect `NULL`s.

```
select * from myTable where category<>"Desktops" or category is null;
```

Comment: The bit about the < and > operator not working with NULL is a vital insight, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

`NOT NULL` is a column constraint and should be used when you have a column that's not in a primary key (primary keys are intrinsically not-null so it's silly to say `NOT NULL` explicitly about them) of which you know the values will always be known (not unknown or missing) so there's no need for nulls in that column.

`NULL` is a keyword occurring in many contexts -- including as a column constraint, where it means the same as the default (i.e., nulls are allowed) -- but also in many other contexts, e.g. to insert a null in a column as part of an `INSERT...VALUES` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Also note that NULL is not equal to anything else, even not to NULL itself.

For example:

```
mysql> select if(NULL=NULL, "null=null", "null!=null");
+------------------------------------------+
| if(NULL=NULL, "null=null", "null!=null") |
+------------------------------------------+
| null!=null                               |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This definition of NULL is very useful when you need a unique key on a column that is partially filled. In such case you can just leave all the empty values as NULL, and it will not cause any violation of the uniqueness key, since NULL != NULL.

Here is an example of how you can see if something is NULL:

```
mysql> select if(null is null, "null is null", "null is not null");
+------------------------------------------------------+
| if(null is null, "null is null", "null is not null") |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| null is null                                         |
+------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 3):

#### If you're not sure, use NOT NULL.

  Despite the common belief, NOT NULL doesn't require you to fill all fields; it just means whatever you omit will have the default value. So no, it doesn't mean pain. Also, NULL is less efficient in terms of indexing, and causes many edge case situations when processing what you receive from a query.
  So, while of course NULL values have a theoretical meaning (and in rare cases you can benefit from this), most of the time NOT NULL is the way to go. NOT NULL makes your fields work like any variable: they always have a value, and you decide if that value means something or not. And yes, if you need *all the possible values* and *one extra value that tells you there's simply nothing there*, you can still use NULL.

#### So why do they love NULL so much?

  Because it's descriptive. It has a semantic meaning, like "Nnah, wait, this is not just an empty string, this is a lot more exotic - it's the
  *lack of information!*
  " They will explain how it's different to say "time is 00:00" and "i don't knot what time it is". And this is valid; it just takes some extra effort to handle this. Because the system will allocate extra space for the information "is there a value at all" and it will constantly struggle checking it out. So for the tiny piece of semantic beauty, you sacrifice time and storage. Not much, but still.
  *(Instead, you could have said "99:99" which is clearly an invalid time and you can assign a constant to it. No, don't even start, it's just an example.)*
  The whole phenomenon reminds me of the good old *isset* debate where people are somehow obsessed with the beauty of looking at a nonexistent array index and getting an error message. This is completely pointless. Practical defaults are a blessing, they simplify the work in a "you know what I mean" style and you can write more readable, more concise, more expressive code that will make sense even after you spend 4 years with other projects.

#### Inevitable NULLs

  If you have JOINs, you will encounter NULLs sooner or later, when you want to join another row but it's not there. This is the only valid case where you can't really live without NULLs; you must know it's not just an empty record you got, it's
  *no record at all.*
  Otherwise? NOT NULL is convenient, efficient, and gives you fewer surprises. In return, it will be called ignorant and outrageous by some people with semantical-compulsive disorder. (Which is not a thing but should be.)

### TL;DR

Prefer NOT NULL when possible.
It's a weird thing - for the machine, too.

Answer (score 0):

**NULLs are Evil!**

OK, I'm kidding, but there are serious pitfalls in the queries when NULLs are present. For example, when comparing NULL to a value, doing SUM, or averaging you need to use COALESCE or ISNULL otherwise you will get incorrect calculations which will lead to errors in your application. And on top of that COALESCE and ISNULL add a very small amount of time to the query execution, and while this extra time can be ignored in most cases, when query needs to evaluate many NULL values in a large table this time can add up.